# How to align a text input with an image button?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a form where the last line of input fields is followed by 2 image buttons.

No matter what I try I can't seem to horizontally align the buttons with the field.

Here's all the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/h3ZPk/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this rule:

```
#buttons img, #buttons input {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h3ZPk/4/)**.

Comment: In case @Ramin is wondering how this works, it's because the `<input>` has 5px of baseline and the `<img>` does not, so the easiest way is to align them to the bottom, although top probably also works.

Answer (score 3):

I don't often recommend this, but please use a table. They are old-fashioned, but they work VERY WELL for forms.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Label1</td><td><input type="text" /></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Label2</td><td><input type="text" /></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Label3</td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="button" /></td><td><input type="button" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT:**

http://jsfiddle.net/h3ZPk/6/

Comment: Yes tables are the answer to all our problems! :D Not sure why everyone is so against them...

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that in the CSS3 era, but concerning forms, they come close!

Comment: A) This isn't tabular data and B) it can be done with just CSS.

Comment: It can be done, but I call it messy, and it requires a sh*tload of code to do something very simple: a table!

Comment: @j08691: What are you sacrificing by using tables? The end result is all that's important.

Comment: And, a small sidenote, tables are compatible with every simple stupid archaic browser that exists in the universe. Sometimes that can be important.

Comment: After 10 years, this recommendation is still useful. Thank you :)