# Aligning icon to inputfield in DIV

Tags: html, css

How to get the square icon in line with the input field?

[image]

```
<td>
    <div class="" id="calc_mat_prijs_pkg_div['.$y.'][]">
        <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="calc_mat_prijs_pkg['.$y.'][]" name="calc_mat_prijs_pkg[]" value="" style="text-align: right" onkeyup="validate(this, '.$y.')">
        <span class="" id="calc_mat_prijs_pkg_glyp['.$y.'][]"></span>

        <span id="calc_mat_prijs_icon['.$y.'][]" class="fas fa-square"></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

I have tried to change the width of the input field to 70% but the icon is still displayed below the inputfield.
`style="text-align: right"` to `style="text-align: right; width:70%"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `<label for="input">...icon...</label><input id="input">`, browser are pre-styled.

Comment: Like this? `<label for="calc_mat_prijs_pkg['.$y.'][]" id="calc_mat_prijs_icon['.$y.'][]" class=""></label>` (same result)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align a text input with an image button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823397/how-to-align-a-text-input-with-an-image-button) and [a multitude of similar answers found by searching SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=align+image+with+input).

Answer (score 0):

My solution applies `position:relative;` to the parent `div` and `position:absolute;` to the `span`. See the HTML and CSS below. I have commented in the CSS regarding the icon being inside `number` input or to the left using `margin-left:25px;`. I hope this helps.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- Added class of field to the div -->
      <div class="field" id="calc_mat_prijs_pkg_div['.$y.'][]">
        <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="calc_mat_prijs_pkg['.$y.'][]" name="calc_mat_prijs_pkg[]" value="" style="text-align: right" onkeyup="validate(this, '.$y.')">
        <span class="" id="calc_mat_prijs_pkg_glyp['.$y.'][]"></span>
        <!-- Added class of icon to the span -->
        <span id="calc_mat_prijs_icon['.$y.'][]" class="icon fas fa-square"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.field {
  position:relative;
}
span.icon {
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
}
input {
  // Remove this margin if you would like the icon inside of the number input
  margin-left:25px;
}
```